# Extracting text features from a dataframe and use them alongside other types of features (heterogenous data) for sklearn purposes: TypeError

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scikit-learn

I am attempting to extract some features from a dataframe that looks akin to this:

```
feature1:float feature2:float feature3:string succeeded:boolean
```

I'm far from an expert on the topic but I attempted the following:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import scipy as sp

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
vectorizer.fit(small_df.feature3)
X = sp.sparse.hstack( (vectorizer.transform(small_df.feature3),
                 small_df[['feature1', 'feature2']),
                 format='csr')

X_columns = vectorizer.get_feature_names() + df[cols].columns.tolist()
```

However, I end up with the following error:
`TypeError: no supported conversion for types: (dtype('int64'), dtype('O'))`

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
X = sp.sparse.hstack( (vectorizer.transform(small_df.name),
                 small_df[cols].values.astype(np.float)))
```